# MySQL Replacing IN and EXISTS with joins in sub sub queries

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, exists

So, this query is currently used in a webshop to retrieve technical data about articles.
It has served its purpose fine except the amount of products shown have increased lately resulting in unacceptable long loading times for some categories.

For one of the worst pages this (and some other queries) get requested about 80 times.

I only recently learned that MySQL does not optimize sub-queries that don't have a depending parameter to only run once.

So if someone could help me with one of the queries and explain how you can replace the in's and exists's to joins, i will probably be able to change the other ones myself.

```
select distinct criteria.cri_id, des_texts.tex_text, article_criteria.acr_value, article_criteria.acr_kv_des_id
from article_criteria, designations, des_texts, criteria, articles
where article_criteria.acr_cri_id = criteria.cri_id
and article_criteria.acr_art_id = articles.art_id
and articles.art_deliverystatus = 1
and criteria.cri_des_id = designations.des_id
and designations.des_lng_id = 9
and designations.des_tex_id = des_texts.tex_id
and criteria.cri_id = 328
and article_criteria.acr_art_id IN (Select distinct link_art.la_art_id
  from link_art, link_la_typ
  where link_art.la_id = link_la_typ.lat_la_id
  and link_la_typ.lat_typ_id = 17484
  and link_art.la_ga_id IN (Select distinct link_ga_str.lgs_ga_id
    from link_ga_str, search_tree
    where link_ga_str.lgs_str_id = search_tree.str_id
    and search_tree.str_type = 1
    and search_tree.str_id = 10132
    and EXISTS (Select *
      from link_la_typ
      where link_la_typ.lat_typ_id = 17484
      and link_ga_str.lgs_ga_id = link_la_typ.lat_ga_id)))
order by article_criteria.acr_value
```

I think this one is the main badguy with sub-sub-sub-queries

I just noticed i can remove the last exist and still get the same results but with no increase in speed, not part of the question though ;) i'll figure out myself whether i still need that part.

Any help or pointers are appreciated, if i left out some useful information tell me as well.

Comment: A very helpful first step to optimizing such a multi-table query is to refactor it to change the join style. Change from the `FROM tab1,tab2 ... WHERE ... tab1.col1 = tab2.col2` style to the `FROM tabl JOIN tab2 ON  tab1.col1 = tab2.col2` style. It's much easier for strangers (like us on SO) to see the logic that way.

Comment: Also, it it recommended to use aliases: `from article_criteria` -> `from article_criteria ac` and then use `ac.acr_value` instead of `article_criteria.acr_value`. In the same direction of thinking - it is not necessary to put table name in column name - `cri_id` can be simply `id`. When there is table prefix `criteria.cri_id` is readable like `criteria.id`. The size of query can be reduced by 30% or even more.

Comment: Thanks ^^
I'll keep it in mind, is my first bigger project using MySQL.

Learning to clean code MySQL somewhat suffered under upcoming deadlines ;)

and i left out table names in my original query, but for the sake of putting the question here i added them.
Otherwise it would be even harder for an outstander to see information belonged to which table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cri_id, dt.tex_text, ac.acr_value, ac.acr_kv_des_id
FROM article_criteria AS ac
JOIN criteria AS c ON ac.acr_cri_id = c.cri_id
JOIN articles AS a ON ac.acr_art_id = a.art_id
JOIN designations AS d ON c.cri_des_id = d.des_id
JOIN des_texts AS dt ON dt.tex_id = d.des_tex_id
JOIN (SELECT distinct la.la_art_id
      FROM link_art AS la
      JOIN link_la_typ AS llt ON la.la_id = llt.lat_la_id
      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT lgs.lgs_ga_id
            FROM link_ga_str AS lgs
            JOIN search_tree AS st ON lgs.lgs_str_id = st.str_id
            JOIN link_la_typ AS llt ON lgs.lgs_ga_id = llt.lat_ga_id
            WHERE st.str_type = 1
            AND st.str_id = 10132
            AND llt.lat_typ_id = 17484) AS lgs
      ON la.la_ga_id = lgs.lgs_ga_id
      WHERE llt.lat_typ_id = 17484) AS la
ON ac.acr_art_id = la.la_art_id
WHERE a.art_deliverystatus = 1
AND d.des_lng_id = 9
AND c.cri_id = 328
ORDER BY ac.acr_value
```

All the `IN <subquery>` clauses can be replaced with `JOIN <subquery>`, where you then `JOIN` on the column being tested equaling the column returned by the subquery. And the `EXISTS` test is converted to a join with the table, moving the comparison in the subquery's `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`.

It's probably possible to flatten the whole thing, instead of joining with subqueries. But I suspect performance will be poor, because this won't reduce the temporary tables using `DISTINCT`. So you'll get combinatorial explosion in the resulting cross product, which will then have to be reduced at the end with the `DISTINCT` at the top.

I've converted all the implicit joins to ANSI `JOIN` clauses, to make the structure clearer, and added table aliases to make things more readable.

Comment: Yes, this gives back the exact same result as my original query did.
Really helpful to get insight in how the join works, thanks ^^ (can't upvote yet, will when i can)

Sadly i see no improvement in speed.
Was i wrong in assuming the sub-queries were being executed multiple times in the first place?
Any other way to improve the speed of this particular query?
I guess maybe making a view out of the sub queries. but llt.lat_typ_id and st_str_id will change from page to page (car_model/type and category_id fyi)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can convert a `FROM tab1 WHERE ... val IN (SELECT blah)` to a join like this.

```
FROM tab1
JOIN (
        SELECT tab1_id
          FROM tab2
          JOIN tab3 ON whatever = whatever 
         WHERE whatever
      ) AS sub1 ON tab1.id = sub1.tab1_id
```

The `JOIN` (an inner join) will drop the rows that don't match the ON condition from your query.

If your `tab1_id` values can come up duplicate from your inner query, use `SELECT DISTINCT`. But don't use `SELECT DISTINCT` unless you need to; it is costly to evaluate.